# Is there a systematic naming system to name carbonyl derivatives?

Tags: nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

I had asked a question earlier about [how the “$\ce{-COOCl}$” functional group would be named](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78630/how-would-the-coocl-functional-group-be-named).

I had received a satisfactory answer that helped me completely understand how that compound was named.

However, I have a much broader question in mind now.

Consider the "$\ce{-COOH}$" functional group. We know that it's called a carboxylic acid group, however I used to think, *why wasn't ethanoic acid simply called as a 1-hydroxyethanal*? I now know that "1-hydroxyethanal" has properties vastly different from both aldehydes and alcohols, and as a result, was named differently to acknowledge this difference. Many acid derivatives have been named (and behave) differently, as a result of the $\ce{C=O}$ group nearby.

[image]

However, these may not be the only molecules that are affected by the nearby $\ce{C=O}$ group. My earlier question had dealt with the $\ce{-COOCl}$ functional group (not to be confused with acyl chloride $\ce{-COCl}$). However, there are a lot more:

[image]

Of course, I did try to name these compounds myself.

1. Cyanide is sometimes treated as a *pseudohalide*, so my guess is **ethanoyl cyanide**.
2. It may be an anhydride of hydrogen sulfide and ethanoic acid, but I'm not very sure.
3. Loong gave me an interesting way to name certain "anhydride" compounds in my previous question. This looks like an anhydride of hydroxylamine and ethanoic acid. So according what Loong told me, my guess is **ethanoic hydroxylamine anhydride**.
4. This one look's rather crazy to me. Had this been posessing a $\ce{C-O-S}$ instead of a $\ce{C-S}$, this would have been an anhydride of sulfuric acid and ethanoic acid. But it's not, so I have no clue on how to name it.
5. This one looks very familiar to an amide, infact a phosphorus analog of amide. For some reason, I feel like calling it **ethanephosphide**, although I don't know why.
6. Like cyanide, even azide is considered a pseudohalide, so my guess is **ethanoyl azide**.

Please keep in mind, I am not asking for the explanations to the naming of all the six compounds I showed above, although it would be great if I could get the names alone. Rather, what I mean to ask is **is there any simplified nomenclature that can deal with all these types of compounds in a simple way?** Although I only showed six, I can go on as long as my imagination permits.

Comment: I think it is a great question. As a suggestion from my side, could someone also comment on how bright is the idea to use an algorithmic name generation bundled with ChemBioDraw/MarvinSketch for these structures?

Comment: I don't know if it's really worthwhile including all your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @orthocresol Well, I asked quite a big question, and it wouldn't be nice if I didn't show a proportional amount of effort that I took before asking someone else to help me.

Comment: If I were to write an answer, I wouldn't really want to pay attention to what you've written. I think that writing the correct answer for 6 compounds, complete with justification, is enough work. I've already spoken out, [on](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3431/16683) multiple [occasions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3816/16683), about my stance that too much effort is not useful. Maybe I'm the only one who thinks that way, but I just wanted to put it out there for consideration.

Comment: These are very different compounds. It's not like you can get whole knowledge of carbonyl compounds' nomenclature in one go.

Comment: Yes @Mithoron, but they all share something in common, the attached $\ce{C=O}$ drastically changes their usual properties. However you're probably right that I simply can't learn the entire carbonyl nomenclature in a single go.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfonic_acid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiocarboxylic_acid

Comment: @Mithoron thank you for your first link, although I was already aware of sulfonic acids. However, are you trying to imply that, in addition to naming it as "alkyl sulfonic acid", we may also name it as "acyl sulfonic acid"?

Comment: @Mithoron, Thank you very much for your second link, that helped me name the second compound completely.

Comment: @orthocresol `If I were to write an answer, I wouldn't really want to pay attention to what you've written.` That is perfectly correct and I feel that's rather a human tendency. However, we do close down simple homework questions because we don't feel like wasting time helping a person who can't help themselves. Also, right now, my main motive is to get an answer. I don't want by any means to discourage any potential answerer by making him think that I don't show as much interest into getting my own answer as the answerer is in trying to answer my question. I may be silly right now, so...

Comment: ... I'd just want to clarify if my thoughts are valid.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphinite

Comment: $\ce{CH3CONH2}$ is not an anhydride.

Comment: @mykhal Whoops sorry, that must've been a typing error.

Answer (score 2):

The names (2 of 6) are rather correct (but note that *acetyl* and  *acetic* names are preferred over *ethanoyl* and *ethanoic*), except following:

2. $\ce{Ac-SH}$: ethanethioic acid, more specifically **ethanethioc *S*-acid** (since there are two possibilities of “monothiation”)

   > **P-15.5.3.4.1**
   >
   > (…)
   >
   > $\ce{CH3-CO-SH}$
   >   thioacetic *S*-acid
   >   ethanethioic *S*-acid (PIN)
   >
   > $\ce{CH3-CH2-CS-OH}$
   >   thiopropionic *O*-acid
   >   propanethioic *O*-acid (PIN)
3. $\ce{Ac-O-NH2}$: Anhydride name cannot be used as hydroxylamine is not a name of acid. It's also not a recognized acid functional group, so the name probably should be regarded a substituted ketone, with preselected prefix *aminooxy* (P-68.3.1.1.1.2), **1-(aminooxy)ethan-1-one**. (Although [pubchem entry](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/177069) lists wrong name: amino acetate; *O*-acetyl hydroxylamine is acceptable I think.)
4. $\ce{Ac-SO3H}$: “α-oxosulfonic acid“, **1-oxoethane-1-sulfonic acid**
5. $\ce{Ac-PH2}$: *phosphide* as alleged analogy to *amide* (with different meanings in inorg. and org. chem.) is not used, the name should be **1-phosphanylethan-1-one** (or acetylphosphane).

   > **P-64.1.2.1** Pseudoketones
   >
   > (…)
   >
   > $\ce{H2P-\overset{1}{C}O-\overset{2}{C}H2-\overset{1}{C}H3}$
   >   1-phosphanylpropan-1-one (PIN)
   >   propanoylphosphane